# SQL Server 2008 Stored Procedure execution issue

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I will try to explain the problem in details. I wrote a SP and executed it successfully. Here it is:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InvoiceReference] 

@StartDate DateTime = NULL,
@EndDate DateTime = NULL,
@DocumentType nvarchar(50) = NULL,
@Partners nvarchar(MAX) = NULL,
@PriceFrom numeric(19,6) = NULL,
@PriceTo numeric(19,6) = NULL,
@VATFrom numeric(19,6) = NULL,
@VATTo numeric(19,6) = NULL,

@PageNumber INT,
@PageSize INT

AS
BEGIN   SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @StartPage as int
    DECLARE @EndPage as int

    SET @StartPage = ((@PageNumber-1) * @PageSize) + 1;
    SET @EndPage = @StartPage + (@PageSize) - 1;


    WITH ResultSet As (select 

    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by d.DocumentID) AS 'RowNumber',
    d.DocNumber, dt.Name as DocumentTypesName, d.Date, p.Name as PartnersName, dd.SalePrice, dd.VAT, (dd.SalePrice + dd.VAT) as TotalSum

    from [dbo].[Documents] d join [dbo].[DocumentTypes] dt on d.TypeID = dt.TypeID
                             join [dbo].[Partners] p on d.PartnerID = p.PartnerID
                             join [dbo].[DocumentDetails] dd on d.DocumentID = dd.DocumentID


    where ((@StartDate is null) or (d.Date >= @StartDate))
    and ((@EndDate is null) or (d.Date <= @EndDate))
    and ((@DocumentType is null) or (dt.Name = @DocumentType))
    --and ((@Partners is null) or (p.Name = @Partners))
    and ((@Partners is null) or (p.Name in (select * from dbo.fnSplitString(@Partners, ','))))
    and ((@PriceFrom is null) or (dd.SalePrice >= @PriceFrom))
    and ((@PriceTo is null) or (dd.SalePrice <= @PriceTo))
    and ((@VATFrom is null) or (dd.VAT >= @VATFrom))
    and ((@VATTo is null) or (dd.VAT <= @VATTo))

    )

    Select * from ResultSet rs WHERE RowNumber between @StartPage and @EndPage

    ORDER BY rs.Date ASC

END
```

But then i found that i had to make a filter by more than one "Partner" (for example: Partner1, Partner2, ...). Then i wrote a function which splitted the SP parameter @Partners in separate strings. But when i commented the old part in the "where" clause and putted the new one (invoking the function i wtrote) it gave me this error message: "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Cyrillic_General_CI_AS" and "Cyrillic_General_CS_AS" in the equal to operation." when i tried to execute the SP. And the error is on line 26, which is:
SET @StartPage = ((@PageNumber-1) * @PageSize) + 1;
and i haven't changed anything there. I read some matirials i found here about collation but i still can't figure the problem out for myself. The function i wrote is:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(200) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your latest tried SP

Comment: I posted it, the only difference with the initial SP is the commented part in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set default collation before comparing result OR before IN Statement.

try your where condition as below:

```
and ((@Partners is null) or (p.Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT in (select * from dbo.fnSplitString(@Partners, ','))))
```

**OR**

```
Set datatype to NVARCHAR of related column
```

Comment: I will try your first suggestion but i have to wait till i get rights to see what is database default collation because i cant now. This may take an hour or more, i will write to you if it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried your first suggestion and my SP executed successfully